# Decode and RequestQueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string

My URL is

```
www.domainname.com/default.aspx?l=en&amp;t=32600483-1618-4f09-9a86-c12de4dafc7b
```

I would love to read the QueryString value of `t`. So i can parse it as GUID.

Unfortunatelly that `&amp;` thing, seems to mess things up.

How can i parse the value of the `t` Query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My URL is

I hope you realize that this is **not a valid URL**. This is a HTML encoded string. Do not confuse with an URL. URLs should be properly URL encoded, not HTML encoded. And since you start with something invalid your only chance is to use some ugly string parsing/regex to extract the necessary information. Since this looks like an HTML encoded string you could HTML decode it first:

```
var myUrl = "http://www.domainname.com/default.aspx?l=en&amp;t=32600483-1618-4f09-9a86-c12de4dafc7b";
myUrl = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myUrl);
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUrl);
var t = values["t"];
```

But I repeat once again: don't do this: tackle the problem at its root. And the root of your problem is the origin of this URL. So if you have control over the generation of this URL then fix it so that you can have a valid URL that you could easily work with with the built-in methods. If you don't have control over the generation of the URL then notify the author of the code that he has a bug in it and ask him to fix it because he has provided you a non-properly encoded URL and you are obliged to use some ugly string parsing mechanisms to extract the information from it.

Comment: Hello! Thank you but why this is not a valid URL?. I use Server.HtmlEncode to create that URL for security reasons, since this text with some other text like "Hello to receive our bonus follow the link below" is rendered within a textbox. What i am missing here?

Comment: It is not a valid url, because in valid urls you have query string parameters separated by `&`. So in the example you have shown you don't have a `t` query string parameter! You have a query string parameter called `amp;t` which obviously is invalid. Please read about URL and HTML encoding and the huge differences between them.

Comment: @ChrisW, of course that it does. Did you try my code? Not that this is a code that I would recommend using. As I said => the problem should be tackled at its root.

Comment: @ChrisW, you can apply `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method when you have a valid URL. As I already stressed in my answer this is **not** the case. The OP has a HTML encoded URL which hardly makes sense. No idea how he ended up with such a string but he should definitely fix the code generating this invalid thing.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The link that you see, is rendered in a textbox with an extra message like "Hello to receive our bonus follow the link below" For security reasons i decided to use the Server.HtmlEncode The whole thing will be sent via email, if the customer decides that. You mean i should not use Server.HtmlEncode ?

Comment: The URL should read `http://www.domainname.com/default.aspx?l=en&t=32600483-1618-4f09-9a86-c12de4dafc7b`

Comment: @Chocol8, I don't know what security reasons you have but you should not use HtmlEncode. You should use HtmlEncode only **before displaying** some string on a web page.